# What are some useful TextMate shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate, textmatebundles

Macs are renowned (or bemoaned) for having an extensive number of shortcuts. However, OS X itself pales in comparison to the shortcut lists in [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) and its bundles.

What are some useful keyboard shortcuts you use?

Comment: Why not just contribute to an existing thread and turn it into a community wiki? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391247/textmate-tips-for-rails-development and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99807/what-are-some-useful-textmate-shortcuts

Comment: I did see those posts. However, I didn't really like the format. Cheatsheets and plugins mixed with tips, etc. That's not really what I'm after. I'm hoping to encourage a massive list of tips similar to the unix tips thread I posted.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

These are my favorite shortcuts:

- <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> Start typing name of a file to open it
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> Select word
- <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> Run the ruby or php-script that is open
- <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> Define a new macro
- <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> Run the macro
- <kbd>opt</kbd> Switch to vertical selection mode
- <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> Edit ends of selected lines

Comment: omg! cmd+opt-a is UBER-USEFUL! Why did't I know it? Thanks a million!

Comment: +1 for vertical selection mode. I've been doing it accidentally for years and now I finally know how to harness its power.

Comment: s/hit the opt key/hold down the opt key while selecting/ ?

Comment: I would add  `1. cmd + a 2. cmd + option + {` to automatically align all the code in your whole file.

Answer (score 21):

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> deletes current line
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> merges current line with the next line

Answer (score 12):

<kbd>Esc</kbd> auto completes common words in the document you are working in.

For example if you are using a function alot called `LongFuntionNameThatChecksStuff`, you can type `Lon` and press<kbd>Esc</kbd> and it should auto complete.

Comment: This loops thru the matching words in order of nearness to your cursor. So might need to hit the escape key a few times to get what you're after.

Comment: I did not know that.. I always assumed it just picked the most common word. That just became a whole lot more useful, thanks

Answer (score 9):

**Control-T**(<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>): *Transpose* (works in most Cocoa-native text fields and areas, but TextMate enhances the behavior).

- Place your caret between two characters, hit <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, and the characters switch places (this is standard Mac behavior).  Awesome for typos.
- Select a word or series of characters on a single line, hit <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, and the characters in the selection will now be reversed (not too useful, but this is a TextMate enhancement)
- Select a series of characters that spans more than one line, hit <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, and the lines will reverse. Characters within the line will still be in order.  Most useful when selecting whole lines, but still works with partial lines selected, just so long as there is at least one newline character selected (TextMate enhancement).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I was searching the menu for "reverse", "flip", "invert", etc. so I could flip some lines around.

Answer (score 8):

My favourites are:

- <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to clean up your indentation
- "lorem", <kbd>TAB</kbd> to insert placeholder text

Answer (score 7):

Personally two of my favourite shortcuts are:

- ⌃⇧L (that's <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>): Which wraps the currently selected text with a link to whatever's in the clipboard, and works for every text language I've tried it in.
- ⌃⇧⌘L (that's <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>): Which googles for the selected text and links to the top result.

The are both super useful for writing text and blogging, (and stackoverflow).

Codewise, I think that I prefer snippets to key shortcuts. Being able to type `if⇥` etc., in almost any language is ridiculously useful, and the consistent interface is what keeps me using TextMate.

I also found [this](http://www.macility.com/images/products/kc/KCTextmate.jpg) quite amusing. But I prefer to learn my shortcuts in small steps, and often find that just looking in the gear menu (⌃⎋) works.

Answer (score 5):

shift+ctrl+alt+v sends selected text to pastie.org

also, using the PHP Bundle, try to start writing a function name and do the following:

str + alt + F3 = list of available functions

str + alt + F1 = short description of the function you've just completed.

Answer (score 5):

Look word up in dictionary, in any Cocoa app (not just Textmate): ctrl + cmd + D

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Wrap each selected line in markup tags: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

For example, if you have:

```
  This is a 
  few sample
  list items
```

Highlight all three lines and presss <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to create:

```
  <li>This is a </li>
  <li>few sample</li>
  <li>list items</li>
```

Comment: Neat, didn't know this could be done. Very useful!

Answer (score 4):

Generate Lorem ipsum: `lorem` + <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Will generate:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>   consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
>   dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
>   veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
>   ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
>   commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
>   dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
>   velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
>   nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
>   occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
>   in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
>   anim id est laborum.

Answer (score 3):

Selecting text using <kbd>alt</kbd> (via click and drag)

then use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> to indent (or <kbd>[</kbd> to dedent)

Answer (score 3):

Delete the current line: <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Format CSS: <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>

Select some CSS and press <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to turn this:

```
body { background: red; font-size: 10px; color: black; }
```

Into this:

```
body {
  background: red;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Look up property specifications in W3C: <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

This works for both HTML and CSS. Place your carrot over whatever property you'd like to look up and press <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>. This will open a new window listing the W3C info.

For example, place your carrot over background:

```
body {
  background: red;
}
```

Hit <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> and you'll see something like:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Edit the end of multiple selected lines simultaneously : <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>OPTION</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Toggle between `{}` and `do` `end` blocks. Place your cursor on the block arugument (i.e. the word after the keyword `do` between the two pipes) and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd>

For example, converts:

```
@post.each do |post|
  puts post.name
end
```

to:

```
@post.each { |post| puts post.name }
```

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> comments out a line and it's smart enough to format based on language. I use it all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Close the nearest open html/xml tag: <kbd>OPTION</kbd> + <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>PERIOD</kbd>

For example, if you have:

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
```

<kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will automatically add the closing `</div>` tag to create:

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Switch between tabs:

- Left: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>
- Right: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>

Comment: It's `Cmd+Alt+[` and `Cmd+Al+]`

Comment: Open the `Window` menu and you will see the actual shortcuts under *Select Next/Previous Tab*.

Comment: Cmd+alt+arrows this combination worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

in the [cftextmate](http://cftextmate.com/) bundle you can type any cfml tag without the opening "<"  or closing ">" and press tab and it completes the entire tag and you can then tab to each of the tag attributes.  i'm not sure if this type of shortcut works for other languages.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a list of shortcut key symbols w/ definitions under **Bundles** > **HTML** > **Entities** - helpful for me in figuring out the whole short-cut bonanza going on with TextMate.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a really great desktop background [here](http://www.wishingline.com/notebook/2007/01/textmateshortcutsdesktop/). It has a ton of really useful keyboard shortcuts. I used it for a couple of days before memorizing the most useful ones.

Comment: That link died, but here's another: [http://blog.libinpan.com/2009/08/textmate-shortcuts-desktop](http://blog.libinpan.com/2009/08/textmate-shortcuts-desktop/)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap selected text in markup tags: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

For example, if you have:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
```

Highlight the text and press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to create:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to File: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Find in Project: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: The "find in project" can be especially useful when looking to do a global find-replace using a regex. Although, be warned, it can be pretty slow.

Comment: Yeah, it is very use full for any kinds of refactoring!

Comment: I gave up on "Find in Project" in favor of the "Ack in Project" bundle.  Much much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate all whitespace / carriage returns between the location of your caret and the start of the next piece of content: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

For example, if you have:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
>   dolore magna aliqua.
>
> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
>   nisi ut aliquip.

Place your caret at the end of the first paragraph and press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to remove the space in between the paragraphs:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.

Answer (score 0):

(these are mostly html-related)

- <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> closes current open html tag
- <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> wrap selection in tags
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd> insert escaped line end, i.e. `\n` or `<br>` depending on the occasion.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and Paste Clipboard: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: Whoa. I didn't know about this. It's a bit different than the standard paste (⌘+v). It seems to move backward thru your clipboard history with each paste. Nice.

Comment: And the nice thing about it is that it includes the clipboard history outside of the Textmate application

Answer (score 0):

Titleize selected text: <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>OPTION</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>

Will turn:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>   consectetur adipisicing elit.

Into:

> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet,
>   Consectetur Adipisicing Elit.

Answer (score 0):

Downcase selected text: <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>

Will turn:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>   consectetur adipisicing elit.

Into:

> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>   consectetur adipisicing elit.

Answer (score 0):

Upcase selected text: <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>

Will turn:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>   consectetur adipisicing elit.

Into:

> LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET,
>   CONSECTETUR ADIPISICING ELIT.